Why doesn't TcpStream::connect_timeout() retry the connection?
I have the following source code that should try to connect to a server for 200 seconds. After that time, it should return an error.
use std::{
    io::{self, Result, Write},
    net::{SocketAddr, TcpStream},
    time::Duration,
};

struct Client {
    channel: Option<TcpStream>,
}

impl Client {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self { channel: None }
    }

    fn connect(&mut self, addr: SocketAddr, duration: Duration) -> Result<()> {
        let connection = TcpStream::connect_timeout(&addr, duration)?;
        self.channel = Some(connection);
        Ok(())
    }

    fn send(&mut self, msg: &[u8]) -> Result<()> {
        self.channel
            .as_mut()
            .ok_or(io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::NotConnected, "Not connected"))?
            .write_all(msg)?;
        Ok(())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut client = Client::new();
    println!("Waiting to connect to server...");
    let result_conn = client.connect(
        SocketAddr::from(([127, 0, 0, 1], 3030)),
        Duration::new(200, 0),
    );

    if result_conn.is_ok() {
        let msg = b"Hi, I am Hernan and this is my first client-server program";
        println!("Sending message: {:?}", msg);
        match client.send(msg) {
            Ok(_) => println!("Message sent"),
            Err(e) => println!("Failed to send message: {:?}", e),
        }
    }
    if let Err(e) = result_conn {
        println!("Fail to connect: {:?}", e);
    }
}

However, when I run the program it immediately returns the error ConnectionRefused instead of trying to connect for 200 seconds as I expected.
I am running this program on Linux Ubuntu 22.04. Why isn't connect_timeout() blocking the execution and retrying the connection for the specified time?
I attach the source code for the server:
use std::{
    io::{Read, Result},
    net::{SocketAddr, TcpListener, TcpStream},
};

struct Server {
    channel: TcpStream,
}

impl Server {
    const MAX_BUFF_SIZE: usize = 128;

    fn new(addr: SocketAddr) -> Result<Self> {
        println!("Waiting for connections...");
        let listener = TcpListener::bind(addr)?;
        let (stream, socket) = listener.accept()?;
        println!("Connection received from {:?}", socket);
        Ok(Self { channel: stream })
    }

    fn recv(&mut self) -> Result<[u8; Self::MAX_BUFF_SIZE]> {
        let mut buff = [0; Self::MAX_BUFF_SIZE];
        self.channel.read(&mut buff)?;
        Ok(buff)
    }
}

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let mut server = Server::new(SocketAddr::from(([127, 0, 0, 1], 3030)))?;
    let msg = server.recv()?;
    println!("Message received: {:?}", msg);
    Ok(())
}


Are you sure you don't have any client already connected to the server?

Yes, I am sure I am running just one client. If I run the client alone (without the server), at least it should wait for 200 seconds and then show the error. But it is not doing that, instead, it is showing the error imediately.

@ChayimFriedman Is it working for you as expected?

" If I run the client alone (without the server), at least it should wait for 200 seconds and then show the error. " - the operating system is handling the sockets, the user space processes just have an interface to it. If no socket is bound and listening on the specified address, then the OS kernel will immediately reject the connection - no server needed for this. Also, nothing in your code is "retrying". All it does is try to establish the connection once and if this fails within 200 ms it will fail.

@SteffenUllrich does this mean that connect_timeout() and connect() have the same effect in this case?

@Lemark: in case of localhost the local kernel can immediately handle the connection attempt. With a remote system though it might be different. connect will start the TCP handshake and a) the other system might respond immediately with SYN+ACK (fine) or RST (failure) or the other system might simply not respond because the SYN got either lost somewhere or got explicitly dropped by some firewall. The kernel will retry sending the SYN if no response was received (the kernel, not the user space process) and the timeout will simply stop no longer wait for the connection to ever succeed.

If the underlying syscall returns failure immediately, yes. The only time connect_timeout does something different is when the underlying syscall returns EINPROGRESS or equivalent

Thank you for the answers. Seems like I misinterpreted the documentation.

I have found a workaround for this problem to make it work with the requirements posted in the question (as @SteffenUllrich suggested to retry the connection). The new version for the cliend should be as follows:
use std::{
    io::{self, Result, Write},
    net::{SocketAddr, TcpStream},
    time::{Duration, Instant},
};

struct Client {
    channel: Option<TcpStream>,
}

impl Client {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self { channel: None }
    }

    fn connect(&mut self, addr: SocketAddr, timeout: Duration, retry_time: Duration) -> Result<()> {
        let start_time = Instant::now();
        loop {
            match TcpStream::connect(addr) {
                Ok(channel) => {
                    self.channel = Some(channel);
                    return Ok(());
                }
                Err(e) => {
                    let elapsed_time = start_time.elapsed();
                    if elapsed_time > timeout {
                        return Err(e);
                    }

                    std::thread::sleep(retry_time);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fn send(&mut self, msg: &[u8]) -> Result<()> {
        self.channel
            .as_mut()
            .ok_or(io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::NotConnected, "Not connected"))?
            .write_all(msg)?;
        Ok(())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut client = Client::new();
    println!("Waiting to connect to server...");
    let result_conn = client.connect(
        SocketAddr::from(([127, 0, 0, 1], 3030)),
        Duration::from_secs(200),
        Duration::from_millis(300),
    );

    if result_conn.is_ok() {
        let msg = b"Hi, I am Hernan and this is my first client-server program";
        println!("Sending message: {:?}", msg);
        match client.send(msg) {
            Ok(_) => println!("Message sent"),
            Err(e) => println!("Failed to send message: {:?}", e),
        }
    }
    if let Err(e) = result_conn {
        println!("Fail to connect: {:?}", e);
    }
}

